# Continue loop sub1 to sub 3 in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Couldn't find this question on StackOverflow, so my apologies when not searched well enough...

I have the following code (simplified)

```
Sub Task_1()
"copy stuff from sheet2 to sheet1"
End Sub

Sub Task_2()
"Print sheet1"
End Sub

Sub Task_3()
"Do ordernumber +1"
End Sub
```

Now I want to loop this. So after sub Task_3, I want to call Task_1 again untill a certain cell is empty. I have the following, but not sure what to put into the questionmark.

```
Sub Start_orderprint()

Call Task_1
Call Task_2
Call Task_3
If Sheet1.Range("A4").Value <> Empty
Then ?????
Else
msgbox "Finished"
exit sub
End if

End sub
```

Comment: Do until or while loops will be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A `Do...Loop` to Run Procedures

- [`Do...Loop statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement)
- [`Using Do...Loop statements`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-doloop-statements)
- But be careful because this may end up being an endless loop (if it never becomes `Empty`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Start_orderprint()

    Do Until Sheet1.Range("A4").Value = Empty
    ' Or
    'Do While Sheet1.Range("A4").Value <> Empty
        Task_1
        Task_2
        Task_3
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub
```

- In the previous example, if the value is initially `Empty`, the loop will never be entered. If you want to enter it once, no matter what, you will have to use the following:

```vb
Sub Start_orderprint()

    Do 
        Task_1
        Task_2
        Task_3
    Loop Until Sheet1.Range("A4").Value = Empty
    ' Or
    'Loop While Sheet1.Range("A4").Value <> Empty
    
    MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub
```